# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil , I define a gesture, this method is the method of gesture binding

Tags: ios, swift, crash

//fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

```
    let translationInContainerView = gesture.translation(in: transitionContainerView!)
```

Occasionally crash,not every time.

I want to catch this exception，in the case of such a situation(found nil)，don't want the program to crash,who can tell me how to solve this problem.

[image]

I try this,but no use:
[image]

Comment: you're using the bang operator (!) to unwrap "transitionContainerView", which is an optional. If you use ! and the value of that object is nil, your app will crash. That's what looks like is occurring here. Use a guard let or if let statement when creating the "transitionContainerView" object in case it is nil. If it is, that's another problem you can handle accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
guard let transitionContainerView = self.transitionContext?.containerView else {
    print("the containerView of transitionContext is nil. Find out why.")
    return
}
```

You might need to cast the transitionContainerView object with a specific type. I don't know what the type is supposed to be but it would look something like this:

```
guard let transitionContainerView = self.transitionContext?.containerView as? MyValueType else {
    print("the containerView of transitionContext is nil. Find out why.")
    return
}
```

The addition here is the **as? MyValueType** portion

If you don't hit the code block within the else statement, then it is not nil and you should be able to use your object accordingly. I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much ! I overlooked the problem may be in the last step

Comment: you're welcome! I'm glad it helped :)